# ufw firewall blocking / logging too much, syslog is getting spammed

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, ufw

I set up ufw firewall on a Debian 12.1 sever. This is my configuration:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
646                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
7886                       ALLOW IN    172.16.0.0/12
7886                       DENY IN     Anywhere
646 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
7886 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

As you can see, first I allow all incoming and all outgoing connection. Then I selectively block a specific port (it should only be accessible from inside). This is working fine.

BUT, my syslog is getting spammed with log entries like

```
[Fr Okt 20 20:32:51 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=36:35:1f:08:90:3f:84:03:28:62:58:18:08:00 SRC=185.11.61.222 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=14551 PROTO=TCP SPT=48993 DPT=62873 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:33:36 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=185.11.61.222 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=59605 PROTO=TCP SPT=48993 DPT=6148 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:33:37 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=77.90.185.189 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=7911 PROTO=TCP SPT=40738 DPT=1999 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:33:49 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=36:35:1f:08:90:3f:84:03:28:62:58:18:08:00 SRC=176.113.115.104 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=17273 PROTO=TCP SPT=57674 DPT=8532 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:34:14 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=36:35:1f:08:90:3f:84:03:28:62:58:18:08:00 SRC=79.124.62.130 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=35581 PROTO=TCP SPT=50976 DPT=41519 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:34:24 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=36:35:1f:08:90:3f:84:03:28:62:58:18:08:00 SRC=46.161.27.54 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=42873 PROTO=TCP SPT=42205 DPT=4477 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:34:55 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=194.26.135.157 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=28309 PROTO=TCP SPT=57742 DPT=9504 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:35:10 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=185.233.19.185 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=15502 PROTO=TCP SPT=58914 DPT=9376 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:35:36 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=36:35:1f:08:90:3f:84:03:28:62:58:18:08:00 SRC=185.11.61.212 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=31908 PROTO=TCP SPT=57640 DPT=50904 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:35:50 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=36:35:1f:08:90:3f:84:03:28:62:58:18:08:00 SRC=80.66.83.76 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=58996 PROTO=TCP SPT=44063 DPT=10749 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:36:04 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=78.128.113.250 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=8239 PROTO=TCP SPT=40186 DPT=35046 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:36:38 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=185.11.61.229 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=20645 PROTO=TCP SPT=49077 DPT=29163 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:36:41 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=62.233.50.217 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=17901 PROTO=TCP SPT=40917 DPT=42703 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
[Fr Okt 20 20:37:17 2023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=46:32:1f:08:90:3f:10:0e:1e:26:f2:c0:18:01 SRC=80.66.83.84 DST=46.127.133.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=25857 PROTO=TCP SPT=43931 DPT=5370 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Logging is set to "low", I read that then ufw will

> store logs related to blocked packets that do not match the current
> firewall rules and will show log entries related to logged rules.

As my default rule is "allow all incoming", **why does ufw block those incoming connection attempts**? Why all those logs?

In case it helps, here's the output of iptables (but I did not touch anything with iptables)

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:1020
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.21.0.2           tcp dpt:25565
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.6           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.6           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.18          tcp dpt:22000
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.18          udp dpt:22000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.2           tcp dpt:2019
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.2           tcp dpt:2015
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.2           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.2           udp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.24.0.2           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             mdns.mcast.net       udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:646
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:646
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.0.0/12        anywhere             tcp dpt:7886
ACCEPT     udp  --  172.16.0.0/12        anywhere             udp dpt:7886
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:7886
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:7886

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warn prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```